# Variable Properties in LESS CSS

Tags: css, less

I am trying to create me a PX/REM converter in LESS CSS but I am facing a problem. 
The following lines do not want to compile, the problem comes from **@{propertyValue}:**.

```
.rem(@propertyValue; @sizeValue) {
  @remValue: @sizeValue / unit(@base-font-size);
  @{propertyValue}: ~"@{remValue}rem";    
}
```

But yet I think the syntax is good... at last I thought!  Can you help me?

Thank you!

Comment: The syntax is correct so make sure you're using a Less compiler that actually supports this feature (so far there're only two such compilers: "official" [Less](https://github.com/less/less.js) and [less.php](https://github.com/oyejorge/less.php) v1.6 or higher).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using at least LESS 1.6? Variables as property names were added in 1.6. Prior to 1.6 there are some solutions but none are pretty.

Your snippet works in this LESS previewer which is running 1.6.0: [less2css](http://less2css.org/)

Comment: Thank you very much, I used the leafo/lessphp which was based on an older version of LESS. I went on lessphp.gpeasy.com, it works perfectly. Thank you again.